# create database using sudo mysql -u=root

Tags: mysql, database, linux, shell, ubuntu

I am having problem rightnow because when I am logging in on mysql using command line via `mysql -u=root` it gives me an error like this `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

but when I try to use `sudo mysql -u=root` I manage to go to mysql promp `mysql>` the problem is when I try to create a database using the command `create database dbname` I got an error that says `ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'dbname'`

Additional informaion:

`mysql> select user();`

```
+--------------------+
| user()             |
+--------------------+
| =root@localhost    |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a database Log into MySQL as root, like this:

```
sudo mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect with

`sudo mysql -u root`